# Is a $k$-differentiable convex function $k$-continuously differentiable?

Tags: calculus, convex-analysis

It is known that a differentiable convex function is continuously differentiable.

Is a $k$-differentiable convex function $k$-continuously differentiable?

Comment: No. You can start out with a $g\ge 0$ and integrate it twice.

Comment: @ChristianRemling a $g$ with intermediate value property. Also, how do you know that $\int g$ is differentiable everywhere, if $g$ wasn't continuous?

Comment: @user251257: We have to choose $g$ properly of course, but that won't be a problem. Something like $G=x^2\sin(1/x)+Ax$, $G'=g$ will work fine.